# Como identificar dependencia binaria Ionic

Tags: android, angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, binario

He intentado de todo: borrar la plataforma de android, el node modules, etc pero sin resultados

**Agradezco cualquier aporte **

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>
>   > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:   Program type already present:
>   >     com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat   Learn how to resolve the issue at
>   >     https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1m 6s
>
> > Task :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED 36 actionable tasks: 16 executed, 20 up-to-date
> >     C:\laragon\www\umbrellaApp\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed
> >     with exit code 1 Error output: Note: Some input files use or override
> >     a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
> >     Note:
> >     C:\laragon\www\umbrellaApp\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\by\chemerisuk\cordova\support\ReflectiveCordovaPlugin.java
> >     uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with
> >     -Xlint:unchecked for details. D8: Program type already present: com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>
>   > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:   Program type already present:
>   >     com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat   Learn how to resolve the issue at
>   >     https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.

Comment: y cuál es el problema?

Comment: asta donde entiendo tengo 2 clases binarias repetidas, pero realmente no se como solucionarlo, Program type already present: com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat gracias por tu gentil respuesta